# Выборка по наличию слова jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно выбрать все элементы у которых текст начинается на "Гл." ? а что после этого текста неизвестно

Comment: нужно выбрать все элементы, и отфильтровать те, у которых текст начинается на "Гл."

Comment: тебе надо пробежаться циклом по ВСЕМ объектам-узлам дерева ДОМ, созданным из элементов твоего документа. для этого я использовал (когда делал похожие вещи) функцию (которая проверяет, а что за объект у меня под рукой - типа ELEMENT или типа TEXT) в цикле for (по списку childNodes для объекта, который в данный момент под рукой, бегал) с рекурсией и счетчик, который считает, насколько глубоко я зашел в объект-узел типа ELEMENT.

Comment: берешь объект поближе к корню, например, html, проверяешь тип его узла, если ELEMENT - заходишь в него и вызываешь опять (рекурсивно) функцию проверки типа узла, если TEXT - заносишь в массив этот узел. когда массив с текстовыми узлами закончит формироваться, то по каждому свойству с числовым именем в цикле пробегись и примени шаблон

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать код такого вида:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if(/^Гл\./.test($(this).text())){
        //необходимые действия над элементом
    }
})
```

Разумеется, вместо селектора "p" вам нужно использовать свой селектор, описывающий общность элементов, среди которых ищем.

Стоит заметить, что здесь мы получим не младший элемент иерархии, в котором непосредственно содержится текст, а "p" (в нашем случае), внутри которого (напрямую или обернутым в любое количество других элементов) текстовое содержимое будет начинаться с "Гл.".

Comment: внутри тега `<p>` может лежать, тег `<span>` или `<a>` и в данном примере нельзя никак определить, проверяется ли текст самого абзаца, либо текст ссылки или спана внутри абзаца

Comment: @Grundy да, вы правы. Но в вопросе не указано, что нужен младший элемент иерархии, как не указано, определен ли пул объектов для фильтрации, или нужно просто найти любые конечные элементы. Я предположил, что у автора есть куча известных элементов `.text`, к примеру, и нужно отфильтровать из них. И в контексте этой задачи вложенные элементы не важны.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын ,  подскажите как быть с Вашим примером если перед Гл. у меня еще куча пробелов?)

Comment: @asdas измените условие на `if(/^(\s*)Гл\./.test($(this).text())){`